Docker compose can’t map directory on under the root
I installed docker pre-installed on Ubuntu 24 system.I want to use docker to load nas-tools and Jellyfin to build a nas.BUT,When I want to map a folder, I find that the folder mapping in the root directory will fail, but the folder mapping in the home directory will succeed.for example:
services:
  nas-tools:
    image: hsuyelin/nas-tools:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:3000 
    volumes:
      - /home/admin//docker-compose/nas-tools:/config 
      - /home/admin/video:/video
    environment: 
      - user=root
      - UMASK=000 

will work good.but:
services:
  nas-tools:
    image: hsuyelin/nas-tools:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:3000 
    volumes:
      - /home/admin/docker-compose/nas-tools:/config 
      - /data1/video:/video
    environment: 
      - user=root
      - UMASK=000 

will failed， /data1 is a folder mounted on another diskI can’t read or write any file in /data1/video by docker volumes.
This is really bothering me. Can someone help me?
I try chmod -R 777 /data1 and change the source dir to /tmp/video but it don't work.

Are you using Docker Desktop?  That can come with limitations like this; but on a native-Linux system, you don't need it (or the hidden Linux virtual machine it runs).  chmod 0777 is almost always a significant security mistake.

Thanks,everyone, I have resolved this problem.
My docker version is sanp docker preinstalled when I install Ubuntu system.
It has restriction:
This build can only access files in the home directory. So Dockerfiles and all other files used in commands like docker build, docker save and docker load need to be in $HOME.

So uninstall the snap docker: sudo snap remove --purge docker.
Install the docker by apt: Install Docker Engine on Ubuntu,it will work!
